# Strange behavior of the ASP.NET Applications Request/Sec performance counter

Tags: iis, asp.net, performance-counters

I have an application that is using `GZIP` compression, which is implemented in a third-party library. This library has a significant impact on processor utilization.

When I disabled this library and enabled [Dynamic Compression module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-compression/iis-compression-overview) in `IIS` instead, I noticed that `ASP.NET Applications Request / Sec` counter values are lower than before, and I don’t understand why.

- Network traffic is the same;
- Number of sessions in load balancer is the same;
- Number of queries to DB is the same.

From the application side, I do not see any problems.

[image: Grafana - perf. counters]